# phpMyAdmin database backup download stops at 5.6MB

Tags: phpmyadmin

Everytime when I download my database by exporting to SQL gzipped file, it stops at 5.6MB. Previously it was ok to download the entire copy of 26MB. What should I do?

Thanks.

Comment: i hope that u have checked the basic things like changing the browser etc. etc.

Comment: Tried different browser. It was working. What's the reason?

Comment: I have same problem..For me its because of internet problem. Need high speed to download it.

Comment: Easy way is use cron and shell to dump the file in server and afterwards you can download it from server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you are on linux even though it sounds nasty try

wget (URL HERE) (directory here)

also check to make sure you have enough room on your computer, try a different browser

Comment: i am guessing that it has to do with how the JavaScript involved is being interpreted by the browser, just out of curiosity what browsers were they?

Comment: @EricFode Same experience here. Failing with Firefox 25-29 (either less than 10MB downloaded or connection broken before starting), no problems with Opera. I guess it has to do with too high transfer rates.